# ¿Cómo construir un flotante en una lista, separar y detectar elementos en una lista en Python?

Tags: python

Estimada comunidad de Stack Over Flow.

Tengo el siguiente código donde por medio de la opción agrego un decimal de 5 o 6 cifras, a la variable numero deseo transformarla una lista, ya que es un flotante.

```
numero = float(str('ingresa numero:   '))

print(numero)
```

Quisiera saber como podria detectar la coma dentro de esa lista y el resto de decimales que hay despues de la coma para convertirlos en otra lista.

Ayuda por favor.

Comment: @CandidMoe SI ya lo analice

Comment: Ingresa el valor simplemente como string (no uses `float`). El tercer dígito sería `numero[2]`. Con eso puedes examinar el número caracter por caracter.

Comment: @CandidMoe ya esta corregido

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero que te sirva, es mas fácil recorrer el str con los metodos buscando el carácter en cuestión que con enteros o decimales.

```
lista = [ 1, 2 , 3, 4.2, 5.36]
lista_nueva = []


for i in lista:
    if type(i) == float:
        variable = str(i)
        index_coma = variable.find(".") +1
        variable2 = variable[index_coma:len(variable)]
        lista_nueva.append(int(variable2))
        
print(lista_nueva)
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

**Nota:** En algunos países la separación entre enteros y decimales es la coma `,` pero en otros es el punto `.`, en esta respuesta utilizaré la coma `,` tal como lo solicitó el OP.

Primero, puedes obtener el valor de número con el método [`input()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) esto permitirá que el usuario agregue el valor a tu programa

```
numero = input('ingresa numero: ')
```

Tal como lo recomendó CandidMoe en su comentario, es mejor utilizar el `input` como `string` para trabajar con el valor ingresado

Si deseas únicamente encontrar la posición de la coma, podrías utilizar el método [`find()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp), esto te devolverá la posición del caracter que buscas. Si utilizamos el número 45,1233456 y hacemos `print(numero.find(','))` el resultado será 2 ya que es el valor del índice del caracter que buscamos (Recuerda que el primer índice es 0, por lo que el índice 0 es `4`, el índice 1 es `5` y el índice 2 es `,`)

Para convertir tu `string` a una lista puedes simplemente utilizar `list()`, de esa forma cada caracter en tu `string` será un valor dentro de una lista

Si desearas separar en dos listas, digamos valores enteros en una lista y valores después de la coma en otra lista entonces podrías utilizar el método [`split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Si utilizamos `split` con el número del ejemplo anterior

```
print(numero.split(','))
```

Esto devuelve

```
['45', '1233456']
```

Con esto podríamos trabajar por separado con los números antes y después de la coma. Al ser una lista, puedes utilizar el índice de la lista que produce `split()` para acceder a los números antes y después de la coma. Por ejemplo, si quisiéramos únicamente los números después de la coma, entonces podemos utilizar el índice `1`

```
print(numero.split(',')[1])
```

Esto devuelve:

```
1233456
```

Y esto lo podemos convertir a lista utilizando `list()`

Ejemplo completo:

```
numero = input('ingresa numero: ')
listaEnteros = list(numero.split(',')[0])
listaDecimales = list(numero.split(',')[1])
print('numero = {}, listaEnteros = {}, listaDecimales = {}'.format(numero, listaEnteros, listaDecimales))
```

Utilizando el mismo número del ejemplo anterior, esto devuelve:

```
numero = 45,1233456, listaEnteros = ['4', '5'], listaDecimales = ['1', '2', '3', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```